# Kafka: Multi-broker architecture

Tags: apache-kafka

I am currently designing a Kafka cluster for our application.

What are the parameters to consider when designing a Kafka cluster?

As per the documentation, multiple brokers can be configured on a single node (Unix box), or multiple nodes with single broker running on each.

Which of these configurations is preferable?

I couldn't find appropriate resources on the internet. Please tag links if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's advisable to run a single broker per box.

For more thorough guidelines, please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296363/7897191